# How to use Twisted python to listen to the events that are exposed in Windows environment

Tags: python, events, twisted

How to use Twisted python to listen to the events that are exposed by an application in Windows environment. and the listened events should be processed in the debian environement.im a beginner in twisted python.
Do help me!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but for your problem there are like a millon solutions.
You need a client / server system. The twisted docs offer several examples.
Go through the "The Evolution of Finger" tutorial and you will get an idea who a client can communicate with a server, also you will learn a lot about twisted.

Answer (score 0):

There may be million solutions, to help you and point you in right direction, see if you can you use RSyslogs https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/omuxsock.html. Then you can use something like twisted python and udp datagram to consume event messages.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31907140)